# Creating a custom view: onMeasure

Tags: android

I'm quite a newbie to android programming and I came across this code for onMeasure at this website: http://www.jayway.com/2012/12/12/creating-custom-android-views-part-4-measuring-and-how-to-force-a-view-to-be-square/

```
private static final float RATIO = 4f / 3f;

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    int width = getMeasuredWidth();
    int height = getMeasuredHeight();
    int widthWithoutPadding = width - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();
    int heigthWithoutPadding = height - getPaddingTop() - getPaddingBottom();

    int maxWidth = (int) (heigthWithoutPadding * RATIO);
    int maxHeight = (int) (widthWithoutPadding / RATIO);

    if (widthWithoutPadding  &gt; maxWidth) {
        width = maxWidth + getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight();
    } else {
        height = maxHeight + getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom();
    }

    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}
```

The code is suppose to take any layout and measure the layout to the ratio 4/3.
They have created variables maxWidth and maxHeight which uses the heightWithoutPadding and widthWithoutPadding respectively - should it not be the other way around? Why are we associating the maxWidth with a height variable?

Also why is the Ratio being multiple with the maxWidth but divided by the maxHeight? If we want the view to be 4/3 of the original ,shouldn't both be multipled by 4/3?

Comment: *Why are we associating the maxWidth with a height variable?* - given a certain width the calculated height will be dependent on this width value. *Also why is the Ratio being multiple with the maxWidth but divided by the maxHeight?* - basic math. You can't multiply both values with the same ratio, one needs to be multiplied with 4/3 the other needs to be multiplied with 3/4.

Comment: I hope I'm not being dumb, but if I have a box 1cm wide and 1cm in height and I want to increase its size by 4/3, I would do this. Width 1cm X 4/3 = 4/3cm wide. Height 1cm X 4/3 = 4/3cm high. By doing what they are doing, you are getting a width of 4/3cm and then a height of 3/4cm which would lead to a disproportionate box?

Comment: You don't have a box. You get two values representing width and height and you're trying to calculate the maximum allowed values for those two dimensions so 
you end up with a 4:3 proportion between them(the width and height being dependent one on which other, 4 * height = 3 * width). You get a height value, from this you 
would calculate the maximum width that is allowed keeping the 4:3 proportion and you multiply the height with 4/3. You get a width value, from this you 
would calculate the maximum height that ...

Comment: ...is allowed keeping the 4:3 proportion and you multiply the width with 3/4. Mathematically you can write this as 
width / (4/3)(so you use the same constant RATIO).